# Adding a field in my mongo query using $cond operator

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I have a collection of documents in which some documents have filed `atd` and others have `etd` inside a nested field `voyage_details`, for example:

```js
[
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "voyage_details" : {
      "atd" : "15-Mar-21"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "voyage_details" : {
      "etd" : "15-Mar-21"
    }
  }
]
```

Now, I want to write a mongo aggregation query where I create a new field on the basis of a condition where if a document has the key `atd` in it then I want to add the value of key `atd` in that new field and if that key is not present in the document then add the value of key `etd` in that new field.

I have written an aggregate query like this to add a new field on the basis of `atd` or `etd` whichever of the both is present inside the `voyage_details` object:

```js
{
  "$addFields": {
    "sailing_date": {
      "$cond": {
        "if": { "voyage_details.atd": { "$exists": True } },
        "then": "$voyage_details.atd",
          "else": "$voyage_details.etd"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone guide me in writing the correct query to add a new field in my mongo aggregation, so that I can use **atd** or **etd** whichever of the both fields present inside the voyage_details section.

Comment: Which MongoDB version are you using?

Comment: I think it is below the version 4 and somewhere around 3.4 or 3.6

Comment: Do you want to update the existing documents in the DB?

Comment: No, I don't want to update them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "sailing_date": {
                "$ifNull": ["$voyage_details.atd", "$voyage_details.etd"]
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Output:

```js
/* 1 createdAt:3/15/2021, 3:36:19 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604f319b9ee8b82dd8cd9f3f"),
    "voyage_details" : {
        "atd" : "15-Mar-21"
    },
    "sailing_date" : "15-Mar-21"
},

/* 2 createdAt:3/15/2021, 3:36:19 PM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604f319b9ee8b82dd8cd9f40"),
    "voyage_details" : {
        "etd" : "15-Mar-21"
    },
    "sailing_date" : "15-Mar-21"
}
```